# Jenkins Userdefined Groups for Active Directory

Tags: active-directory, jenkins

We use Jenkins in our company and I want to use the existing ActiveDirectory to setup access rights.

I want to group people together to make the access matrix in Jenkins as small as possible.

Now the problem is, that I'm not allowed to create new groups in the Active Directory, so my question is:
Is it possible to create user-defined groups inside Jenkins to combine ActiveDirectory-users?

Answer (score 0):

Yes, Jenkins recognizes groups in the Active Directory. For example, setup matrix-based security and use a group like "Domain Admins".